# Capturing parameters from a string represented in quotations and commas

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I have a string which is like this

`"81.213.224.141","81.213.224.141","UAE","United Emirates","D3","Dubai","WildWadi","","32.100000","3.200100","Telecom","Eutelsat - SanComm"`. What I am currently working on is to only get the data between the quotations while avoiding commas and store them in different strings. So String 1 has the first IP, String 2 has the second IP, String 3 has country code and etc.

For `"Eutelsat - SanComm"` I would like to split it into two and store them in two strings. So first string would have `Eutelsat` and the second would have `SanComm`.

So far I have managed to split the string however it is not only taking the data between quotations as well as it is not viewing fully e.g. only `Telecom` out of the entire information.

Code:

```
str_Info = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ") //str_Info is a string having the TextBox 
                                      Which in turn has the string shown above

    For Each str_get As String In str_Info

    Next
End Sub
```

I think my splitting is not satisfying my requirement. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
    Dim noQuotes = Textbox1.Text.Replace("""", "") ' Remove quotes
    Dim split = noQuotes.Split(",") ' Split on commas

    Dim result As New List(Of String)()

    For Each str_get As String In split
        Dim splitStr = str_get.Split("-") ' Perform secondary split on dash
        For Each str_split As String In splitStr
            result.Add(str_split.Trim()) ' Enter into result list
        Next
    Next
```

Your list of values will be in `result`

Comment: OK, how can I view the completed capturing of the data in a textbox? which string I should display?

Comment: As you requested: `result(0)` has the first string, `result(1)` has the second etc...

Comment: ok, can I view result(0) and result (1) both of them in one Label?

Comment: `Label1.Text = result(0) & result(1)`

Comment: ok I tried it and it is showing me this error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index". Also what if the dash is in a different place, would that change the end result or require a change in the code?

Comment: Make sure your index does not pass `result.Count`. I suggest you debug and see for yourself, it returns 13 results just like you requested

Comment: So far I have got two labels, one has `result(0)` and the other has `result(1)`. When I debugged, It shows that Label1.Text has the first IP address, however Label2.Text has the word `Label` but not the second IP address. The `result` string Count is = 1 where `(0)` has the `81.213.224.141` but `(1)` is not showing. ??

Comment: I updated my answer to show the exact usage with the string you gave. Hope this answers all your problems...

Comment: Sorry, I am just being able to get the first IP and not able to get any other data. There is only one double quotation between each parameter not 2 nor 3.

Comment: @HumamShbib - Either you incorrectly posted your string in the question **or** you haven't copied my answer correctly. You wrote *and I quote* `I have a string which is like this`.... So you have **1 string** which has quotes and commas - Is this correct?? If so, the code I wrote will work perfectly. Put that entire string in TextBox1.Text and then run the code above - you will get a variable named `result` with 13 strings inside.

Comment: My string is correct and I copied your code correctly. As I mentioned earlier I am able to fetch the first `result(0)` but not able to fetch `result(1)(2).....(13)` to show them in a label as it shows the `Index was out of range error`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20171/discussion-between-blachshma-and-humam-shbib)

Comment: @HumamShbib: Indices in .Net are ZERO-based. If you have 13 elements, you have index 0 to 12. NOT 13!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the Textfieldparser:

```
    Dim tfp As New TextFieldParser("data.txt")
    With tfp
        .HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
        .SetDelimiters(",")
    End With
    Dim fields = tfp.ReadFields
    For Each field In fields
        Debug.Print(field)
    Next
```

Now you can do what you want with each field.
If you want it more strong typed, you could use [www.filehelpers.net](http://www.filehelpers.net) where you can create a class that is then "deserialized" from your input.

With Filehelper it could look like:

```
Private Class SatlistConverter
    Inherits ConverterBase

    Public Overrides Function StringToField(from As String) As Object
        Return Strings.Split([from], " - ").ToList
    End Function
End Class

<DelimitedRecord(",")>
Private Class TheRecord
    <FieldQuoted>
    Public IP1, IP2, ISOCountry, Country, Something, City, Region, SomethingElse, Lattitude, Longitude, Provider As String
    <FieldQuoted, FieldConverter(GetType(SatlistConverter))>
    Public Satlist As List(Of String)
End Class

    Private Sub foo()

    Dim e As New FileHelperEngine(Of TheRecord)
    Dim records = DirectCast(e.ReadFile("data.txt"), TheRecord())
    For Each r In records
        Debug.Print(r.IP1)
        Debug.Print(r.IP2)
        For Each s In r.Satlist
            Debug.Print(s)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

There is much more possible with Filehelper, but as a jump start it might be sufficient.

Personally I like the idea to get something more strongly typed (note that you can use built in converters to make "2" an integer for example) and not just an array of string.

**EDIT** Updated sample to show use of a CustomConverter